# Datagridview edit not updating database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview bound to "ParsreelsBindingsource". When I edit the DGV the canges show without an error, but is not updatting the database. I use the following code to save :

```
   Private Sub UPDATE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UPDATE.Click, UPDATE.Click

    Me.Validate()
    Me.ParsreelsBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.SkeduleringDatabasisDataSet)
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

Regards

EDIT : CODE FOR Dataset : (I hope this is what what you want)

```
           Partial Class SkeduleringDatabasisDataSet
           End Class

           Namespace Skedulering.SkeduleringDatabasisDataSetTableAdapters

          Partial Public Class ParsreelsTableAdapter
          End Class
          End Namespace
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your data set?

Comment: How do you know it isnt updating - how do you check?  And what is the DB (SQL is not a DB)/

Comment: Side issue: `Handles UPDATE.Click, UPDATE.Click` - delete the ", UPDATE.Click" as it will cause the `UPDATE_Click` method to run two times.

Comment: I have edit my question to include the code for my dataset. Plutonix I know it is not updatting as I can see that if I open the SQL Database, Regards

Comment: (SQL is not a DB) When I open the table in the server explorer and view the data nothing has been changed. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Any time I've had to deal with datagridviews the following has worked fine

```
Friend Class MyClass

    Private daFoo as dsMyDataSetTableAdapters.TableFooAdapter = new dsMyDataSetTableAdapters.TableFooAdapter()
    Private dtTable as Datatable

    Private Sub setUpTheDGV()
        dtTable = daFoo.GetMyData()
        myDGV.DataSource = dtTable
        Refresh()
    End Sub

    'Do things, call methods, change the datagridview's contents....

    Private Sub updateMyData()
        daFoo.Update(dtTable)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The changes made to the datagridview are applied to the datatable, and the adapter does all the heavy lifting on a .update call. Hope it helps.